# Do Reflex skills that affect "rifles and SMG" affet sniper/precison rifles?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

The "Assault" branch in the "Reflex" skill tree has lots of skills that affect "rifles and submachine guns". For example:

> Bullet Jock (Passive) [3 levels]: Increases damage with **Rifles and Submachine Guns** by 3% (at level 1). 
> Eagle Eye (Passive) [3 levels]: Reduces time to aim down sight with **Rifles and Submachine Guns** by 10%.
> Executioner (Passive) [1 level]: Deal 25% more damage with **Rifles and Submachine Guns** to enemies whose Health is above 50%.

There is ONE perk that mentions sniper rifles and precision rifles:

> Nerves of Steel (Passive) [2 levels] {Requires Level 11 Reflexes}: Increases headshot damage with **Sniper Rifles and Precision Rifles** by 20% (at level 1)

Also, there is one that specifies only assault rifles:

> Feel the Flow (Passive) [2 levels] {Requires Level 11 Reflexes}: Reduces reload time for **Assault Rifles and Submachine Guns** by 10%.

So, maybe it is a silly question, but do all perks that mention only the word "rifle" work with all types of rifles (assault/precision/sniper)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.

It is only for balancing sake that those two skills are only applied to Sniper/Precision, and Assault Rifle/SMG.

If AR/SMGs could do extra damage on headshots, it would be a overpowered since they already do pretty good damage, and it's fully automatic with manageable recoil (Additionally, there's skill called "Skull Skipper", that comes with *Each headshot reduces recoil with rifles and SMGs by 5% for 10 seconds. Can stack up to five times*).

Having the ability to reload faster would be spectacular, considering how much damage Sniper/Precision can do with so little ammo in the magazine. In terms of DPS, they would be kings if they could reload more quickly.

The other skills are just for "Rifle" in general (Assault Rifle, Sniper Rifle, Precision Rifle).